# Visual Studio 17.6.2 requires WSL for running console applications

Tags: console-application, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-2022

I have just installed the new version of Visual Studio Community Edition (version 17.6.2). Now, I have a project with a *Console application* project in NET7. Usually I can run this console application and it runs in a normal shell window.

After the upgrade, the Console Application requires WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Why? Now, Visual Studio shows an error popup message:

[image]

Click on `OK`, it opens the *Microsoft Store* and I click on *Debian*.

[image]

After few seconds, in the PowerShell window I get this message

> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
>
> Error: 0x80370114 The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

[image]

So, I open a new PowerShell window and I try to install manually a Linux distribution using

```
wsl --list
wsl --list --online
wsl --install Ubuntu-22.04
```

but again I get the same error.

[image]

This is the project properties

[image]

First question: why I can't run the console application as usual? An then, why do I need WSL (that I have installed any way)? How can I fix the issue?

### Update

If in the property of the project I select as target OS `Windows`, the application is still running in the *Output* window. Basically, Visual Studio doesn't open a prompt window to run the application.

[image]

### Options

The *Terminal* under *Environment* in the *Options* has as default `Developer PowerShell`.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't created wsl project or debug configuration that targets wsl?

Comment: I created this project 6 months ago and it was running in a common Prompt window. I have just added the screenshot of the console application properties

Comment: Try changing the target OS from NONE ?

Comment: Can you check what the default terminal is set to? Tools => Options => Environment => Terminal. Maybe WSL is set as the default terminal, when you want PowerShell

Comment: @Lennart the default is Developer PowerShell. I added a scrennshot.

Answer (score 3):

Locate the file launchSettings.json that is placed under your project folder, in sub-folder "Properties".

Then edit the file and remove the following bunch of lines:

```
> "WSL": {
>       "commandName": "WSL2",
>       "distributionName": ""
>     },
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi the error message indicates that you didn't install/enable wsl successfully.

In order to fix the error WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
You need to turn on the windows feature "Virtual Machine Platform".